# Errors on a Test Class Unexpected error: @

Tags: apex, trigger, compile-error

This should be a very straightforward Test Class, but I get an error at line 1: unexpected token: @

```
@isTest
private class AccountCreatedNewCase {

    @isTest static void createAccount() {
        Account myAccount = new Account ();
        myAccount.AccountName = 'Salesforce';
        insert myAccount;


    }


}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger AccountCreatedNewCase on Account (after insert) {

    // 'after insert' instead of 'before' because we need Account ID (account created) before case is created

    for (Account a: Trigger.new) { 

    // Trigger.new defines the list of records that go into the loop
        Case c = new Case();
        c.Subject = 'Dedupe this Account';
        c.OwnerId = 'XXXXXXXXX'; // ID info from user page 
        c.AccountId = a.Id; 

        // Check API name for Account related to a case - it says AccountId
        // 

        insert c; 

        }

}
```

Comment: This trigger seems extremely misguided in general. You should look at the **[`Duplicate Management`](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=managing_duplicates_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0)** feature.

Comment: For what it's worth, I copied the class into my dev org and the error I got was on `myAccount.AccountName = 'Salesforce';` because there is no standard field called 'AccountName'. If I change that to the right field name the class compiles and runs.

Comment: I am trying to learn apex. So I am doing simplistic triggers and test classes. You are correct. I should have said myAccount.Name = 'Salesforce'; I still get the same error: unexpected error @

Comment: Is the code in your post copied and pasted from your class? Is that all that's in it?

Comment: Code is copied from both test class and class. That's all there is in it.

Comment: I just recopied the testclass (word by word) and this time it didn't show any problems. Thank you John for trying to help me!

Answer (score 4):

It is common when pasting code for it to contain hidden characters that bork the compiler. This is one of many risks of copy-paste programming.

Avoid the copy-pasta and type it out each time. You will learn better that way. It will force you to think more carefully about the code you are creating, because you are actually writing it.